# Designing an ad for ConLang SE

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

***Calling anyone with some graphic design skills!*** Want to design an ad for this site?

Graduated sites all over SE have Community Promotion Ads - advertisements designed, vetted, and chosen by the community which appear on the sidebar of the site. Many of these ads are for other, 'neighbouring', SE sites, to encourage good relations and flow of views and traffic between sites.

There are quite a number of sites - including [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://fantasy.stackexchange.com), [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com), [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com), [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) and more - whose scopes bear some relevance to constructed languages. These would be great places to place ads for this site and get traffic flowing here.

We could just use the default [Area 51 proposal ad](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10796/87724), but it's not very pretty. **Would anyone like to design a better one?** It doesn't have to be some great work of art - just something nice and eyecatching which has some relevance to constructed languages.

---

Image requirements (for SE Community Promotion Ads):

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

Answer (score 7):

Great idea!

I would suggest making creative use of the wider [Constructed Language Community flag](https://conlang.org/conlang_flag.svg) as it is widely recognisable as a language invention symbol.

Suggestion 1: Superimposition of symbology:

[image]

Suggestion 2: Incorporation of symbology:

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea! Can you post it as a PNG so it won't be dithered? We'll want some sort of text along with this.

Comment: They now point to the png versions. What kind of text?

Comment: Version 2 looks really cool. Great artwork!

Comment: I think the integrated symbology better depicts what we're about here, too.

Comment: It was great to see version 1 with additional text "Built your world? Now build your language" on [worldbuilding.se] just now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my entry. The concept by @elemtitas. Made in Adobe Illustrator, exported as `.png`.
[image: Tower of Babel with SE colours.]
Also: `.svg`, `.ai`.
Vote [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6209/33241), [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11466/217886) and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11914/101240). 6 votes are required to appear as an add.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what languages are "lingvoj" and "Fle'iroqia"? (And do we want to promote one or two conlangs above others in the Community Ad? Or is that just my pedantic love of symmetry?)

Comment: Lingvoj is Esperanto (the most well-known), fle'iroqia (as you said, in order to not promote something) is a word I made up (using some phonology of one of my draft languages that never was developed).

Comment: Though I like the general idea, I'm not sure about these language choices... I had been thinking that site specific language choices might work better. Klingon and Tengwar for Scifi, some weirder looking ones for world building for example. If I have time to make some ads I'll put them up here for the rest of you to consider

Comment: @curiousdannii Tengwar is [not a language](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Tengwar), it's a writing system invented by Feanor for the Elven languages.

Comment: @Edlothiad I'm aware... I started off talking about languages but then switched to writing systems, could have been clearer.

Comment: @curiousdannii ah I see, my apologies.

Comment: So, why aren't the other choices in those votes?